# How to 'link binary with libraries' with framework in '$Users/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData'

Tags: ios, xcode

I have 1 XCcode project which has a framework as its Products. When I right click that framework and 'Show in Finder', the path of the framework is  '/Users/hap497/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData'

And I want to use this framework in my other XCode project. So I go to this project 'Link binary with libraries' and click 'Add files'. In the popup window, it does not show me the path 'Library' under my user name. In other words, it does not let me select the directory  '$Users/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData'.

So my question is how to add the framework which is under  '$Users/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData' to my Xcode project?

Comment: Just out of curiosity, how did you add that framework to the first project?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following shortcut will reveal hidden files & folders:

`cmd + shift + .`

HOWEVER....

I'd strongly recommend **against** *manually* linking to anything in `DerivedData` (unless you really know what you're doing); otherwise you could end-up facing issues later on (missing files, wrong architecture, etc).

You should use a package manager for this like [SPM](https://www.raywenderlich.com/7242045-swift-package-manager-for-ios) or [Cocoapods](https://cocoapods.org/) instead.

Hope this helps!